# How to restrict access to custom gerrit plugin

Tags: gerrit

As part of Gerrit plugin development my requirement is to provide a "button" which should invoke certain operation on a Gerrit change but not all the Gerrit-user-groups should be able to see "that button" on the UI page. Only approved groups should be able to hit that button.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to take a look at the sources of other plugins. For *example*, the *Checks plugin*, registers a custom `Administrate Checkers` permission ([1](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/checks/+/86594f00fcd784ea722cd5ae34e287ace72cf3df/java/com/google/gerrit/plugins/checks/AdministrateCheckersCapability.java), [2](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/checks/+/86594f00fcd784ea722cd5ae34e287ace72cf3df/java/com/google/gerrit/plugins/checks/AdministrateCheckersPermission.java)) and in ([3](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/checks/+/86594f00fcd784ea722cd5ae34e287ace72cf3df/java/com/google/gerrit/plugins/checks/api/UpdateChecker.java#75)) it checks whether a user has this permission granted for a change in that context (via the backend, like any other Gerrit ACL). The frontend (PolyGerrit) displays some options/buttons conditionally based on that permission in ([4](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/checks/+/86594f00fcd784ea722cd5ae34e287ace72cf3df/gr-checks/gr-checks-view.js#91)), but of course the backend should be authoritative for the check to perform the action.

Hope this helps a bit!

The example I gave is for PolyGerrit and should work for ~ 3.0 & upcoming 3.1.

Don't hesitate to get in touch via the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/repo-discuss) in case you need some more help for specific questions.

Comment: Hi gertvdijk, this is quite helpful to start with, Thanks ! .